# Dynamic Views not keeping input

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment in a Tabbed Activity, that creates new view when a button is clicked, the problem is that when the view is created and the information is filled in with different information and I swipe to a different fragment and then back all of the views that where created with the button click now contain the same information.

In the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if(view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_history, container, false);
    }
    Button addHistoryButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddHistory);

    inflaterM = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext());
    root = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutHistory);
    mListener.onFragmentHistoryInteractionLoad();

    addHistoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_history_layout, null);
            child.setId(View.generateViewId());
            root.addView(child);
        }


    });

    return view;
  }
```

R.layout.list_history_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHistory">

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextStory"
    android:hint="Story"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextYearRecorded"
    android:hint="Year Recorded"
    android:inputType="date"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create properties on your fragment that you can set when a change happens on your view, for instance:

```
private boolean mHistoryButtonAdded;

...

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_history_layout, null);
        child.setId(View.generateViewId());
        root.addView(child);
        mHistoryButtonAdded = true;
    }
```

Next, you need to override `onSaveInstanceState()` to preserve these properties, for example:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("history-button-added", mHistoryButtonAdded);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
```

Then, in your `onCreateView()`, you would check for these properties and recreate the view from their state, for example:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    mHistoryButtonAdded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("history-button-added", false);
    if (mHistoryButtonAdded) {
        View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_history_layout, null);
        child.setId(View.generateViewId());
        root.addView(child);
    }
}
```

Also make sure you use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, this will save and restore the state.